# Need to perform 2 Javascript button clicks on page load

Tags: javascript

I need a script that will click a button on page load but I can't get it to work. I can throw the javascript line into firebug and it works fine...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("evcal_next").click();
</script>
```

in the head section of the page... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you execute this when there isn't an element with id `evcal_next`. You can either :

- put this script at end of your body instead of in the head
- change it to execute on document load

The second solution would be like this :

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById("evcal_next").click();
});
</script>
```

EDIT

To "click `evcal_next` then pause for a few miliseconds, then click `evcal_prev`", you can do this :

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById("evcal_next").click();
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("evcal_prev").click();
    }, 2000); // 2 seconds
});
</script>
```